# Can we use nested FormulaArray to compute the maximum for all interval in a time series?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I trying to use FormulaArray to compute the maximum values for all fixed length intervals within an time series. For example, let say we have Column A for "dates" and Columna B for "values", I am trying something like

```
ArrayFormula(Max(Filter(B1:B, DAYS(A1:A,A1:A) > t, DAYS(A1:A,A1:A) < 2*t)))
```

where t is some constant. This is, for each row i, I wanna compute the

```
MAX(FILTER(Bi:B, DAYS(Ai:A,Ai) > t, DAYS(Ai:A, Ai) < 2*t))
```

I amlooking a solution using ArrayFormula o alternative but no using Query.

Comment: Could you add an example of the data that you have and the result you would like? If you share a spreadsheet with the minimum necessary data (read permission is enough) it would help a lot

Comment: Also, is there a reason for you not wanting to use query?

Comment: This is an [example]( https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BaBQIv4yszlIlopFWQ5c1n58R8eD5sbFwfi5CT7uQU4/edit?usp=sharing)

I wanna see if ArrayFormula can be useful or I need to dive more in the query syntaxis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to use `MAX` or `QUERY` on each row using `ARRAYFORMULA`. The reason for that is that formulas "consume" the entire range. This makes it more difficult. The way of doing this is first generating a table with all the values and then use `QUERY` to make the maximum for each column.

### Step 0: Prepare useful information

There are 2 values that will become really handy. The first is `t`. I've set it to 2 on `E2`and added a header. The second one is the number of values that we have. This needs a formula and will go to `F2`:

```
=MAX(ARRAYFORMULA(if(A:A<>"";row(A:A);0)))-1
```

The formula is basically the number of the last non empty row minus 1 (because we skip 1 row, the headers).

### Step 1: Table with all the numbers

The formula is:

```
=
ARRAYFORMULA(
  IFNA(
    IF(
      A2:A<>"";
      VLOOKUP(
        A2:A+SEQUENCE(1; E2+1; E2);
        A2:B;
        2;
        false
      );
      ""
    );
    -9999
  )
)
```

You need to add it on row 1 or 2 to have enough rows (it expands to the last possible row).

The main trick is that `SEQUENCE(1; E2+1; E2)` will be `{2; 3; 4}` when t equals 2. array formula combines this with A2:A to make a 3 wide 2D array. See how it expands it:

```
=
ARRAYFORMULA(
  A2:A+SEQUENCE(1; E2+1; E2)
)
```

You'll notice that they have the values of the days that you'd like to take the value from.

Then we use `VLOOKUP` to convert this "indexes" into the actual values. Add an `IF` and a `IFNA` to prevent problems and you got it!

### Step 2 Remove the empty rows

This step makes it simpler later on since you work with less data that we are not interested in anyways. To do so we can simply add an `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN`:

```
=
ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
  TRANSPOSE(
    <formula on step 1>
  );
  E2+1;
  F2
)
```

### Step 3.1 Adding the query into the mix

The query operates column-by-column. This means that we need to transpose the values, operate using query, and transpose back to the original orientation. This looks something like:

```
=
TRANSPOSE(
  QUERY(
    TRANSPOSE(
      <formula on step 2>
    );
    <query>
  )
)
```

### Step 3.2 Generating the Query

Now that we have the values correctly we need to generate the query. This is because the number of columns will grow.

The basic query would be:

```
select MAX(Col1), MAX(Col2), MAX(Col3) label MAX(Col1) '', MAX(Col2) '', MAX(Col3) ''
```

The select part is quite self-explanatory. The lebel part is used to remove the headers, so we only get the values.

To generate the values we need to generate `MAX(ColN)`. This can be achieved with `ARRAYFORMULA` together with `SEQUENCE`:

```
=
ARRAYFORMULA("MAX(Col"&SEQUENCE(F2)&")"
```

We add  `''` at the end in the case of the labels so it would be:

```
=
ARRAYFORMULA("MAX(Col"&SEQUENCE(F2)&") ''"
```

Now we join them with comma and put the entire query together:

```
=
"SELECT "&
JOIN(
  ",";
  ARRAYFORMULA("MAX(Col"&SEQUENCE(F2)&")")
)&
" label "&
JOIN(
  ",";
  ARRAYFORMULA("MAX(Col"&SEQUENCE(F2)&") ''")
)
```

### Step 4: Putting everything together

If you put everything together you get:

```
=
TRANSPOSE(
  QUERY(
    TRANSPOSE(
      ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
        ARRAYFORMULA(
          IFNA(
            IF(
              A2:A<>"";
              VLOOKUP(
                A2:A+SEQUENCE(1; E2+1; E2);
                A2:B;
                2;
                false
              );
              ""
            );
            -9999
          )
        );
        F2;
        E2+1
      )
    );
    "SELECT "&
    JOIN(
      ",";
      ARRAYFORMULA("MAX(Col"&SEQUENCE(F2)&")")
    )&
    " label "&
    JOIN(
      ",";
      ARRAYFORMULA("MAX(Col"&SEQUENCE(F2)&") ''")
    )
  )
)
```

### References

- [ARRAYFORMULA (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [VLOOKUP (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)
- [QUERY (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [SEQUENCE (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244)
- [JOIN (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077)
- [ARRAY_CONSTRAIN (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267036)
- [TRANSPOSE (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)
- [IF (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [IFNA (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! wow, you really worked out this solution. thanks for the comment. sadly, looks like there was no simple solution :(